# How do I grab std output from a netcat listener subprocess from my Java program that I executed using Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdLine)?

Tags: java, subprocess, inputstream, bufferedreader, netcat

I'm using netcat to test a udp port forwarder, and am unable to programmatically read the string from the destination (a netcat listener subprocess). What is the correct stream to read from my netcat listener subprocess to see if a message was forwarded to the listener correctly? Currently I am reading from the listener subprocess' INPUT STREAM, but I am having trouble getting this to work. I have read that Process.getInputStream() is actually the parent process' input stream, and corresponds to the subprocess' stdout, but perhaps this is the wrong stream to grab??

First I start my udp port forwarder subprocess, which will forward anything coming in on localhost:srcPort over to localhost:destPort.

Next I start a netcat listener along with and two "draining" threads - one to read from the listener subprocess' error stream, and one from its input stream.

```
Process recvProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("nc -luv -p <destPort>");
```

Then I start a netcat sender to send a string to the port forwarder, along with 2 draining threads:

```
Process sendProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("nc -vu <srcHost> <srcPort>");
```

And finally, I send the string over:

```
String sendString = String.format("hello%s", System.lineSeparator());
PrintWriter sendWriter = new PrintWriter(sendProcess.getOutputStream());
sendWriter.print(sendString);
sendWriter.flush();
```

If I run the netcat listener from a cmd window instead, the sendString is output correctly to the console. But from my Java program, the read on the listener's inputStream blocks. Here is the run() method of my listener's inputStream read thread:

```
BufferedReader in;
try {
    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(receiveMsgProcess.getInputStream()));
    String receivedMsg;
    while ((receivedMsg = in.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(String.format("RECV IN: %s", receivedMsg));
    }
} catch (...) { ... }
```

I thought it might be a newline issue, so I also tried using the in.ready() and in.read(buffer, 0, 1024) methods instead of in.readLine(). They all block.

I also tried to redirect the output of my listner to a file:

```
Runtime.getRuntime.exec("nc -luv -p <destPort> > recvMsg.txt");
```

but this does not work either, no file is created.

Please help, I'm pretty sure I'm just misunderstanding something about netcat and java Process streams. Thank you in advance for any suggestions or insights.

Comment: Check the error stream as well.  Sometimes processes send to both and on a standard command prompt they look the same.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion... but I do check the error stream as well. I get the following on the error stream: "listening on [any] <port>", "connect to [host] from [host] <port>". But no sendString.

Comment: Can anyone confirm whether the recvMsgProcess.getInputStream() is the correct stream to grab?

Comment: I'm also having this problem. I'm pretty sure `getInputStream()` is right.

Answer (score 1):

read the errorStream for output of nc command.

```
StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
BufferdReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(recvProcess.getErrorStream()));
String line="";
while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
    response.append(line + "\n");
}
System.out.println(response.toString());
```